# react-pdf: Argument of type 'FunctionComponentElement is not assignable to parameter of type ReactElement<DocumentProps, JSXElementConstructor<any>>

Tags: next.js, react-pdfrenderer

I can generate a PDF on a Nextjs api route with the library **react-pdf**, by using the data sent via request.

But the issue arises with the method `ReactPDF.renderToStream()`, which requires the type below:

> 'ReactElement<DocumentProps, string | JSXElementConstructor>'.

When I try to pass the props to make a PDF on demand, typescript complains about the types like below:

> 'FunctionComponentElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<DocumentProps, string | JSXElementConstructor>'.
> Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
> Type 'PdfBudgetProps' has no properties in common with type 'DocumentProps'.

The command that created this type issue was:

```
  const pdfStream = await ReactPDF.renderToStream(
    React.createElement(PdfBudget, {month: "jan"})
  );
```

Below is how I created the component:

```
import { Document, Page, Text } from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import React from 'react'

interface PdfBudgetProps {
  month: string;
}

const PdfBudget: React.FC<PdfBudgetProps> = ({month}) => {
  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <Text>{month}</Text>
      </Page>
    </Document>
  )
}

export default PdfBudget
```

And below is the api route:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { renderToStream } from "@react-pdf/renderer"
import PdfBudget from '../../../components/PdfBudget'

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  
  if (req.method != "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({message: "invalid method"})
  }
  
  // Stream the PDF directly to the response
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="example.pdf"')
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
  
  const pdfStream = await renderToStream(
    React.createElement(PdfBudget, {month: "jan"})
  )

  pdfStream.pipe(res)
}
```

How to solve the type issue?

I appreciate any help!